# Can any solution to the three-dimensional wave equation be written as a superposition of plane waves?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, superposition

Can any solution to the three-dimensional wave equation, $$\nabla^2f = \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2},$$ be written as a superposition of sinusoidal plane waves? In "Introduction to Electrodynamics" Griffiths points out that sinusoidal waves are of interest because any solution to the *one-dimensional* wave equation, $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} = \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2},$$ is a superposition of sinusoidal waves, but that doesn't necessarily mean that any solution to the three-dimensional wave equation can be written as a superposition of sinusoidal plane waves.

Comment: Yes. The scalar wave equation is linear no matter what dimension it's in.

Answer (score 2):

In a simplified effort let's focus on integrable functions $L^1$ and assume solutions of the wave equation $f\in L^1$:
$$
f(r,t) = \int dk d\omega \exp(\text{i}( k\cdot r + \omega t)) \hat{f}(k,\omega)
$$
$$
(\Delta - v^{-2}\partial^2_t)f = 0
$$
Putting the fourier-integral definition of $f$ into the wave equation yields
$$
0 = \int dk d\omega (v^{-2}\omega^2 - k^2)\exp(\text{i}( k\cdot r + \omega t)) \hat{f}(k,\omega) \forall r,t
$$
Now the only way this may work if the only nonvanishing $\hat{f}(k,\omega)$ are the ones with $(v^{-2}\omega^2 - k^2) = 0$, since $\exp(\text{i}( k\cdot r + \omega t))$ are linearly independent, and this characterizes exactly the plane waves.