# Any three-dimensional wave can be expressed as a combination of plane waves?

Tags: waves

I encountered the statement that ***any three-dimensional wave can be expressed as a combination of plane waves***, each having a distinct amplitude and propagation direction. My studies so far have been focused on the harmonic wavefunction

$$\Psi(\mathbf{r}, t) = Ae^{i(\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r} \mp \omega t)},$$

so I'm very curious as to what this statement means.

I did find and read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476118/141502) question, but I found the answer to be uninformative (too dissimilar from my starting point of $\Psi(\mathbf{r}, t) = Ae^{i(\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r} \mp \omega t)}$).

I was wondering if someone would please take the time to elaborate on this statement. Showing this through mathematics is, of course, appreciated, but please take care to do so slowly and carefully, since I am a novice and might otherwise quickly get confused. Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand how waves in *one* dimension can be written as a superposition of sinusoidal waves with different wavelengths?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, I understand the principle of superposition (and things like interference that come with it). That's what you're referring to, right?

Comment: The quick of it is that (most) waves can be expressed as an infinite sum of plane waves with amplitudes set by the Fourier components of the wave. There are some mild restrictions on how discontinuous the wave may be for this to work, but these are usually irrelevant for physical waves. The problem here is rather: what level of math would make sense to you?

Comment: I was asking more about your understanding of Fourier analysis in one dimension.

Comment: @G.Smith Oh, no, I haven't learned Fourier analysis yet.

Comment: OK. Then I recommend learning about it in 1D before moving on to 3D.

Comment: @AndersSandberg I'm ok with common PDEs, but I haven't yet learned Fourier transforms or expansions.

Comment: @G.Smith Ok, so this all has to do with Fourier analysis applied to plane waves?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Here is a gentle intro: http://www.complextoreal.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/fft1.pdf

Comment: @G.Smith I guess I'll have to wait till I finish learning Fourier analysis, then. I've currently been working at it anyway. Thanks for the clarification.